# WinRT element rendering bug

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-8.1

for some unkown reason the elements in Windows 8.1 Preview are not displayed properly. It looks like this.
[image] Some elements are fine (ListView), some are broken (ToggleSwitch) and some doesn't show at all (Button). Usually it happened when the page was loaded for the second time. 
Is there any way how to reload a page or do something that fix this?

Comment: Does it display correct in Win8 ?

Comment: It did and I also believe that it worked for some time in 8.1. But at some point I switched from Debug to Release profile and it is broken.

It doesn't matter which profile I choose now. I also tested it on multiple PC and ARM devices. It is always broken like this. (All the PCs had 8.1 installed as I use some 8.1 only features, like SearchBox.)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any specific Theme declared anywhere (or in multiple places)? Are you using the new RequestedTheme feature on your UIElements?

Comment: I do. I edited template on SearchBox and I styled ItemTemplate in GridView. Also, in the App.xaml I have RequestedTheme set to Light, but I use on multiple places RequestedTheme set to dark (mostly on CommandBar).

Comment: Tim, would it help if I send you my app?

Comment: Vlad - I'm happy to take a look -- I don't need source (unless you have a simplified repro) but a package would be good so that I could install something.

Comment: Great! Could you please send me a mail at stackoverflowalias@outlook.com? I will send you what I have.